# Firebase Web - forEach with limitToLast

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In a database reference, how can you iterate over its last n children? Something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/path').on('value', function(data) {
    data.limitToLast(n).forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.val());
    });
});
```

I tried something similar to the above snippet, but I got an error:

```
TypeError: data.child(...).limitToLast is not a function [Learn More]
```

So I think there is no `limitToLast()` method for a datasnapshot. Then I tried `forEach()` on a database reference with `limitToLast()`, but I got an error; I think database references don't have a `forEach()` method.

How do I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[limitToLast()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToLast) is a method on Query (and Reference), not on [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).  You use it when specifying your query, so that the server only returns the number of elements you're looking for in the snapshot that's delivered to your callback.

```
firebase.database().ref('/path').limitToLast(n).on('value', function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.val());
    });
});
```